# Android: Listview Items not Showing

Tags: android, android-listview, android-custom-view, baseadapter

My items for Listview are not showing, can someone point me where is the error.
There is no error when adding items but its not showing on the Listview. I revised my post, I'm trying to use BaseAdapter to populate the items. I can confirm that the items are added to the database because the total amount is updated everytime i add item.

```
public class ViewTransactions extends Activity {

private ListView mListViewTransactions;
private TransactionAdapter mAdapter;
private List<TransactionModel> mListTransactions;

/** transactions data source. */
private TransactionDao transactionSource;

/** Currently selected broker, as specified by intent received from ViewBrokers class. */
private BrokerModel currentBroker;

/** The sum total of all transactions for the active broker. */
private BigDecimal brokerTotal;

private ArrayAdapter<TransactionModel> aa;

/** Action mode for the context menu. */
private ActionMode aMode;
/** Call back methods for the context menu. */
private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {

    /** Title which displays broker name. */
    private TextView title;



    // Called when the action mode is created; startActionMode() was called
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        // Inflate a menu resource providing context menu items
        MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_transactions, menu);

        // disable listener here; moved from onPrepareActionMode
        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.exCat);
        title.setClickable(false); // prevent navigation away from activity
        return true;
    }

    // Called each time the action mode is shown. Always called after onCreateActionMode, but
    // may be called multiple times if the mode is invalidated.
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.exCat);
        title.setClickable(false); // prevent navigation away from activity
        return false; // Return false if nothing is done
    }

    // Called when the user selects a contextual menu item
    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_edit:
                // edit selected expense
                editTransaction();
                mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
                return true;
            case R.id.action_del:
                // delete selected expense
                deleteTransaction();
                mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    // Called when the user exits the action mode
    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        // unselect item that was selected (if it wasn't deleted)
        final ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.tList);
        lv.clearChoices();
        lv.setItemChecked(lv.getCheckedItemPosition(), false);

        lv.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
            }
        });
        aMode = null;

        title.setClickable(true); // restore broker name click
    }
};


/**
 * Class to asynchronously retrieve transactions from database.
 */
private class GetTransactions extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<TransactionModel>> {

    @Override
    protected List<TransactionModel> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // retrieve all transactions for the user and broker
        return transactionSource.getTransactions(currentBroker);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final List<TransactionModel> result) {

        mAdapter = new TransactionAdapter(ViewTransactions.this, mListTransactions);

        mListViewTransactions.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mListViewTransactions.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            // Called when the user long-clicks on an item
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> aView, View view, int i, long l) {
                if (aMode != null) {
                    return false;
                }
                mListViewTransactions.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
                // mark item at position i as selected
                mListViewTransactions.setItemChecked(i, true);
                // Start the CAB using the ActionMode.Callback defined above
                aMode = ViewTransactions.this.startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}

/**
 * Class to asynchronously add new expense to database.
 */
private class AddTransaction extends AsyncTask<String, Void, TransactionModel> {

    @Override
    protected TransactionModel doInBackground(String... params) {
        return transactionSource.newTransaction(params[0], new BigDecimal(params[1]), params[2],
                currentBroker);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(TransactionModel result) {

    //    ArrayAdapter<TransactionModel> aa = (ArrayAdapter<TransactionModel>) getListAdapter();

        mAdapter = new TransactionAdapter(ViewTransactions.this, mListTransactions);

    //    mAdapter.add(result);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        // update total
        brokerTotal = brokerTotal.add(result.getTransactionAmount());
        TextView total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.transactionTotal);
        NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
        total.setText(formatter.format(brokerTotal));
    }
}

/**
 * Class to asynchronously edit an expense in database.
 */
private class EditTransaction extends AsyncTask<TransactionModel, Void, TransactionModel> {
    @Override
    protected TransactionModel doInBackground(TransactionModel... params) {
        return transactionSource.editTransaction(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(TransactionModel result) {
    //    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

     //   ArrayAdapter<TransactionModel> aa = (ArrayAdapter<TransactionModel>) getListAdapter();
        aa.notifyDataSetChanged();

        // update total
        brokerTotal = brokerTotal.add(result.getTransactionAmount());
        TextView total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.transactionTotal);
        NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
        total.setText(formatter.format(brokerTotal));
    }
}

/**
 * Class to asynchronously delete an expense from database.
 */
private class DeleteTransaction extends AsyncTask<TransactionModel, Void, TransactionModel> {
    @Override
    protected TransactionModel doInBackground(TransactionModel... params) {
        return transactionSource.deleteTransaction(params[0]); // delete selected item from db
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(TransactionModel result) {
     //   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
     //   ArrayAdapter<TransactionModel> aa = (ArrayAdapter<TransactionModel>) getListAdapter();
        aa.remove(result); // remove selected item from adapter
        aa.notifyDataSetChanged();

        // update total
        brokerTotal = brokerTotal.subtract(result.getTransactionAmount());
        TextView total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.transactionTotal);
        NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
        total.setText(formatter.format(brokerTotal));
    }
}

/**
 * Method to record a new expense. Called when Add button in action bar is clicked.
 */
private void addTransaction() {

    // build dialog to ask for expense details
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Record Transaction");
    builder.setMessage("Please enter transaction details.");


    // construct input fields
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    final EditText enterDate = new EditText(this);
    final EditText enterCost = new EditText(this);
    final EditText enterDesc = new EditText(this);

    enterDate.setHint("Date");
    enterCost.setHint("Amount");
    enterDesc.setHint("Transaction");

    enterDate.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME); // date text
    enterDate.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(40)});

    enterCost.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED); // to accept dollar amount
    enterCost.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789.-")); // accept digits

    enterDesc.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES); // description text
    enterDesc.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(40)});

    ll.addView(enterDate);
    ll.addView(enterCost);
    ll.addView(enterDesc);
    builder.setView(ll);

    // add ok and cancel buttons
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null);
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null);

    // create dialog
    final AlertDialog dia = builder.create(); // don't show yet

    // set listener to description input field to click OK when done
    enterDesc.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
       @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            boolean handled = false;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                // click dialog's OK when user presses Done on keyboard
                dia.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).performClick();
                handled = true;
            }
            return handled;

        }
    });

            // set listener to date input field to click OK when done
            enterDate.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                    boolean handled = false;
                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                        // click dialog's OK when user presses Done on keyboard
                        dia.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).performClick();
                        handled = true;
                    }
                    return handled;
        }
    });

    // set input mode to let keyboard appear when dialog is shown
    dia.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);

    dia.show();

    // override onclick for OK button; must be done after show()ing to retrieve OK button
    dia.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // retrieve name entered
            String date = enterDate.getText().toString().trim();
            String cost = enterCost.getText().toString().trim();
            String desc = enterDesc.getText().toString().trim();

            // perform checks and add if pass
            if (cost.equals("")) { // must not be empty
                enterCost.setError("Please enter an amount.");
            //} else if (!Pattern.matches("^(\\d{1,10})?(\\.\\d{0,2})?$", cost)) { // must be $$
              //  enterCost.setError("Please enter a valid amount.");
            } else {
                // can be added
                new AddTransaction().execute(date, cost, desc);
                dia.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Method to edit selected expense. Called when Edit button is clicked in context menu.
 */
private void editTransaction() {
    // retrieve adapter and retrieve selected expense
 //   ListView lv = getListView();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 //   final ArrayAdapter<TransactionModel> aa = (ArrayAdapter<TransactionModel>) getListAdapter();
 //   final TransactionModel exToEdi = aa.getItem(lv.getCheckedItemPosition()); // get item at checked pos

    // build dialog to ask for expense details
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Edit Transaction");
    builder.setMessage("Please enter transaction details.");

    // construct input fields
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    final EditText enterDate = new EditText(this);
    final EditText enterCost = new EditText(this);
    final EditText enterDesc = new EditText(this);

//    enterDate.setText(exToEdi.getTransactionDate());
//    enterCost.setText(exToEdi.getTransactionAmount().toString());
//    enterDesc.setText(exToEdi.getTransactionDescription());

    enterDate.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME); // description text
    enterDate.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(40)});
    enterCost.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER); // to accept dollar amount
    enterCost.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789.")); // accept digits
    enterDesc.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES); // description text
    enterDesc.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(40)});

    ll.addView(enterDate);
    ll.addView(enterCost);
    ll.addView(enterDesc);
    builder.setView(ll);

    // add ok and cancel buttons
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null);
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null);

    // create dialog
    final AlertDialog dia = builder.create(); // don't show yet

    // set listener to description input field to click OK when done
    enterDesc.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            boolean handled = false;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                // click dialog's OK when user presses Done on keyboard
                dia.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).performClick();
                handled = true;
            }
            return handled;
        }
    });

    // set listener to date input field to click OK when done
    enterDate.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            boolean handled = false;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                // click dialog's OK when user presses Done on keyboard
                dia.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).performClick();
                handled = true;
            }
            return handled;
        }
    });

    // set input mode to let keyboard appear when dialog is shown
    dia.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);

    dia.show();

    // override onclick for OK button; must be done after show()ing to retrieve OK button
    dia.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // retrieve name entered
            String date = enterDate.getText().toString().trim();
            String cost = enterCost.getText().toString().trim();
            String desc = enterDesc.getText().toString().trim();

            // perform checks and add if pass
            if (cost.equals("")) { // must not be empty
                enterCost.setError("Please enter a dollar amount.");
            //} else if (!Pattern.matches("^(\\d{1,10})?(\\.\\d{0,2})?$", cost)) { // must be $$
            //    enterCost.setError("Please enter a valid dollar amount.");
            } else {
                // can be changed
            //    brokerTotal = brokerTotal.subtract(exToEdi.getTransactionAmount());
            //    exToEdi.setTransactionAmount(new BigDecimal(cost));
            //    exToEdi.setTransactionDescription(desc);
            //    exToEdi.setTransactionDate(date);
            //    new EditTransaction().execute(exToEdi);
                dia.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Method to delete selected expense. Called when Delete button is clicked in context menu.
 */
private void deleteTransaction() {
    // get list view and list adapter
//    ListView lv = getListView();
//    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
//    ArrayAdapter<TransactionModel> aa = (ArrayAdapter<TransactionModel>) getListAdapter();
//    int pos = lv.getCheckedItemPosition(); // get pos of selected item
//    TransactionModel del = aa.getItem(pos); // get item in adapter at position pos
//    new DeleteTransaction().execute(del); // delete expense async and update total
}

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.capital_activity_view_transactions);


    initViews();

        currentBroker = (BrokerModel) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(IntentTags.CURRENT_BROKER);
    // set totalCost = ; here

    // set title to broker
    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.exCat);
    title.setText(currentBroker.getBroker());
    title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent it = new Intent(ViewTransactions.this, ViewBrokers.class);
            startActivity(it);
        }
    });

    // open data source
    transactionSource = new TransactionDao(this);
    transactionSource.open();

    // display total for user, cat, month/year
    brokerTotal = transactionSource.getTotalCost(currentBroker);
    TextView total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.transactionTotal);
        NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
        total.setText(formatter.format(brokerTotal));

    new GetTransactions().execute(); // retrieve display transactions for the broker
}

private void initViews(){

    this.mListViewTransactions = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.tList);
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    transactionSource.open();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    transactionSource.close();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.view_transactions, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_new) {
        addTransaction();
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.switch_user) {
       // Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewUsers.class);
       // startActivity(intent); // start user activity
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

```
    public class TransactionAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public static final String TAG = "ListTransactionsAdapter";

    private List<TransactionModel> mItems;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public TransactionAdapter(Context context, List<TransactionModel> listBrokers) {
        this.setItems(listBrokers);
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return (getItems() != null && !getItems().isEmpty()) ? getItems().size() : 0 ;
    }

    @Override
    public TransactionModel getItem(int position) {
        return (getItems() != null && !getItems().isEmpty()) ? getItems().get(position) : null ;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return (getItems() != null && !getItems().isEmpty()) ? getItems().get(position).getId() : position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(v == null) {

            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.capital_row_layout_transaction, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.txtCapitalTransactionDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.capital_broker_date_transaction);
            holder.txtCapitalTransaction = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.capital_broker_add_transaction);
            holder.txtCapitalTransactionAmount = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.capital_broker_add_amount);

            v.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        // fill row data
        TransactionModel currentItem = getItem(position);
        if(currentItem != null) {

            holder.txtCapitalTransactionDate.setText(currentItem.getTransactionDate());
            holder.txtCapitalTransaction.setText(String.valueOf(currentItem.getTransactionDescription()));
            holder.txtCapitalTransactionAmount.setText(String.valueOf(currentItem.getTransactionAmount()));

        }

        return v;
    }

    public List<TransactionModel> getItems() {
        return mItems;
    }

    public void setItems(List<TransactionModel> mItems) {
        this.mItems = mItems;
    }

    class ViewHolder {

        TextView txtCapitalTransactionDate;
        TextView txtCapitalTransaction;
        TextView txtCapitalTransactionAmount;
    }

}
```

Comment: First of all, you should split your code in different classes, so that it'd be easier to find out whatever error. Then I didn't find your adapter class, so please show us

Comment: I updated the post with the adapter.

Comment: Make sure your `mListTransactions` is coming full from ` transactionSource.getTransactions(currentBroker)`

Comment: I added this "mListTransactions=transactionSource.getTransactions(currentBroker);

Comment: It only show the hint's on my row views not the actual values I entered.

Comment: `mListTransactions` seems to be without values. Debug your code and create a breaking point into `getView ` from your adapter, so that you will be able to see if `TransactionModel currentItem = getItem(position);` is returning right values

Comment: I resolved already. There was a mistake on my TransactionModel class.